# Accessing DOM element in Vuejs component not reliable

Tags: vue.js, dom, dom-manipulation

In the simplified example below I demonstrate my problem:

1. I have a for-loop that asynchronously updates `myItems`.
2. I want to be able and update accordingly `selectableItems` by using `this.$el.querySelector('selectable-item')`.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <p>selectableItems: {{selectableItems}}</p>
    <div v-for="item in myItems" class="selectable-item">item</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      myItems: [],
      selectableItems: [],
    }
  },
  created(){
    // Populate myItems with a delay
    self = this
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.myItems = [1, 2, 3]
    }, 1000);
  },
  mounted(){
    // Fetch some of myItems based on a class
    this.selectableItems = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.selectable-item')
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

I've tried many different things I've found online; TickNext, computed, updated, etc. I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. But it is important for my case to be able and select DOM elements by  a class.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

**Updated: More context**

Some people asked me for the bigger picture so I give a bit more info here.

Currently I have a big Vue component where the user is able to select elements. I am trying to factor out all this user interaction into a mixin so I can re-use it in other places of my code.

To make re-usability easy I need to be able and simply add a class `selectable` to any HTML tag in the template. That's the interface and then the mixin does all the magic and populates `selectedElements` depending on user interaction.

That's why it is important to avoid refs, etc. since then too much logic leaks everywhere and beats the purpose of making the mixin re-usable. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: is there any reason why you're not using $ref?

Comment: your selectableItems is also not going to work since you're not using `this.selectableItems`

Comment: @A.Lau yes, because I'm trying to decouple my original code into a mixin so the class is the best way to keep it generic..

Comment: I don't think you're using vuejs appropriately. Might be better off using slots or something. Best to describe what outcome you want, rather than how to use vuejs as though it was just jquery.

Comment: I would love to see a bit more of the problem statement and some additional code, because right now it looks like you're adding the class `selectable-item` to every item in `myItems` so your code could just be boiled down to deleting your entire `mounted()` block and just using `myItems`

Comment: @maxshuty this is a simplified example. I've added more info now for the real-life scenario. Essentially it boils down to making a very generic mixin.

Comment: @Pithikos why not just add a property to `myItems` like `myItems[0].selected = true` then you can key off of that everywhere (assuming you are able to pass around `myItems`) or easily get all selected items `const selectedItems = myItems.filter(i => i.selected)`. It seems like a code smell to be trying to query all elements with a given class for this solution

Answer (score 0):

OK, after trying many different things I've managed to solve this by using a non-reactive intermediate variable. This means that I can't use the variable in a template but that is fine.

```js
export default {
  ..
  // NOT reactive so you can't just use it in your templates.
  _selectableItems: [],

  updated(){
    self._selectableItems = self.$el.querySelectorAll('.selectable-item')
  },
  ..
}
```